# How can I simply parse a stand-alone razor template and use the output as an email body in c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, razor, razorengine

I've looked at a dozen or so ways to do this and I'm having a very hard time getting things to work. The issues I've run into fall into one of two categories:

1) A full MVC setup is assumed in the examples I'm looking at. In my case, I'm sending an email from a WebApi project and will not be using any of the pre-wired MVC view functionality provided by the ASP.NET project stub.

2) Libraries are asking for some complex setup I don't really think I need, specifically RazorEngine asking me to set up a TemplateManager, when all I need to do is give a .cshtml file a model and get the parsed results back.

Pardon the noob question; I'm working on my first .NET project here. Thanks!

Comment: Check: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1):

I had to do the same thing for different reasons a while ago. I had found this class that I used to render the view into a string: https://github.com/RickStrahl/WestwindToolkit/blob/master/Westwind.Web.Mvc/Utils/ViewRenderer.cs

Use it like this:

```
var r = new ViewRenderer();
var renderedView = r.RenderViewToString("~/Views/MyView.cshtml");
```

If you need to pass a model to the view, call it like this:

```
var renderedView = r.RenderViewToString("~/Views/MyView.cshtml", model);
```

Where `model` is what your view expects.